# Why is this python-panda operation returning an error?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file consisting in three columns of bitcoin history, looks like this:

```
1500326826,2174.000000000000,0.027612680000
1500326826,2174.000000000000,0.158374090000
1500326826,2174.000000000000,0.100000000000
1500326834,2174.000000000000,2.000000000000
...
```

I'm trying to get the OHLC of intervals of 10 minutes like this:

```
data_frame= 
 pd.read_csv('./btcmag/raw_initial_currency_data/krakenUSD.csv',
 names=['Date_Time', 'Price', 'Volume'], index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

data_price = data_frame['Price'].resample('10Min').ohlc()
```

I tried different ways, for exmaple:

```
data_price = data_frame.resample('10Min').ohlc()
```

But always get this in the command line:

```
   data_price = data_frame['Price'].resample('10Min').ohlc()
  File "/Users/john/.virtualenvs/btcmag/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4729, in resample
    base=base, key=on, level=level)
  File "/Users/john/.virtualenvs/btcmag/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 969, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "/Users/john/.virtualenvs/btcmag/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1091, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
TypeError: 
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, 
but got an instance of 'Int64Index'
```

I'm a total newbie at this and not even reading through the docs I can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Before setting data_price try `data_frame["Date_Time"] = data_frame.to_datetime(data_frame["Date_Time"], unit="s"`.  I'm guessing Pandas doesn't realize the 10 digit integer is seconds sense epoch so you'll need to convert it first with `unit='s'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
data_frame= pd.read_csv('./btcmag/raw_initial_currency_data/krakenUSD.csv',  names=['Date_Time', 'Price', 'Volume'], index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

data_frame.index = pd.to_datetime(data_frame.index, unit='s')

data_price = data_frame['Price'].resample('10Min').ohlc()
```

Comment: It works! Could you briefly explain why and what I was doing wrong?

Comment: when you were applying ohlc(), it was considering Date_Time column as an integer because time was in seconds. So I converted it in datetime format with **pd.to_datetime(data_frame.index, unit='s')**.